# How to return Value after ifPresent Check

Tags: java

I am trying to return empName if its present Or else Empty String
But i am unable to return .
After ifPresent its not allowing me to return value , please help need with the syntax .

This is my Structure

```
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeData {
    
    private List<Employee> employees = null;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

This is my Employee class

```
public class Employee {
    
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My Test Program

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        EmployeeData empData = new EmployeeData();
    }

    public String getEmpName(EmployeeData empData)
    {
          Optional.ofNullable(empData.getEmployees()).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                  .stream().findFirst().ifPresent( 
                            return   emp->emp.getName();
                  )).orElse{
                            return "";            
                   }
    }

}
```

Comment: empName of who ? Of anyone of the employees ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any name of one of the employees you need to `map` to their name, then use `findFirst` and `orElse`.

The `ifPresent` is to consume the data and only if their is a data : here you want to return **and** do something if not present

```
public String getEmpName(EmployeeData empData) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(empData.getEmployees()).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                   .stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .map(Employee::getName).findFirst().orElse("");
}
```

Comment: so this will return the name of the first Employee data know

Comment: How to avoid NPE  , incase the Employee getName is null , its throwing NPE .

Comment: @Lavanya I've a `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` in the stream